# Load function written in amd64 assembly into memory and call it

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-construction, jit

I am trying to write a small jit compiler. For that, I need to somehow load new code into memory and then execute it.

Given the output of the compiler for a function that simply adds the 2nd and 3rd argument

```
push %rbp
mov %rsp, %rbp
sub $44, %rsp
movl %esi, -4(%rbp)
movl %edx, -8(%rbp)
#     return a+b
movl -4(%rbp), %esi
movl -8(%rbp), %r11d
addl %r11d, %esi
movl %esi, %eax
leave
ret
```

I save my compiler output to a file, called `subfunction.S` and translate it via `as -o subfunction.o subfunction.S`.

I then try to load it into memory and execute it as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

typedef int (*fun_pointer)(int, int, int);

int main(){
    FILE *f = fopen("subfunction.o", "r");

  if (f)
  {
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int length = ftell(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    char *memory = mmap(NULL,   // address
                        length+10, // size
                        PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC,
                        MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS,
                        -1, // fd (not used here)
                        0); // offset (not used here)
    if (memory)
    {
      fread(memory, 1, length, f);
      fclose(f);
      fun_pointer function = memory;
      int res = function(0,1,2);
      printf("RESULT: %d", res);
      fflush(stdout);
    }
  }
}
```

Note that my assembly code contains no external references (with regard to linking).

This unfortunately does not work (=> Segfault)(*). My guess is, that my compilation step using `as` is not appropriate to create binary data that can be executed from memory. I also tried using `ld` (with tmp.o as input) and load the output of it into memory. Again with no success.

(*) Actually changing `sub $44, %rsp` to `sub 44, %rsp`, which makes no sense, as 44 is interpreted as memory location causes no segfault (but also no return value). This leads me to think that it might be some kind of alignment issue?

Comment: Note that the assembler *assembles,* it does not *compile.*    The problem is that the object file produced by the assembler has headers and metadata, it's not just the code you typed.  If you just want the code, convert to binary with `objcopy -O binary`.

Comment: For future problems like this, I recommend you use a debugger to inspect what exactly is happening.

Comment: Thank you very much! This resolved the issue. If you want the reputation you could submit it as a reponse and i would be more than happy to flag it as an answer. Also i will try to use gdb in my setting to solve such issues by my own in the future.

Comment: Test `mmap` for success by comparing the return value to `MAP_FAILED`, not to `NULL`.  I think that some OS setups might be configured to refuse to create a write+execute mapping (so-called `W^X` rule).  In that case you can write the code, then `mprotect` to switch from writable to executable.  (An alias mapping is also possible but more complicated to set up.)